# How to make UserControl locked to certain height?

Tags: winforms, user-controls

A user is not allowed to resize a `TextBox` control vertically. The height of a `TextBox` is locked to the ideal height that a textbox should be.

What's more, Visual Studio doesn't even provide you vertical drag handles:

[image]

How do i provide the same mechanism on my `UserControl`?

Comment: It has a custom designer.  Override the ControlDesigner.SelectionRules property.

Comment: @IanBoyd - simply make the textboxs MultiLine property false (and lock the property) in your user control

Comment: @JeremyThompson My `UserControl` does not contain a `TextBox` - it's a user control.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will elaborate on Hans' comment.  You can associate specialized code (called a Designer) with a UserControl so that when it is placed on a form in Visual Studio, the user is limited in how they can configure your control.

1. Add a reference to `System.Design` in your project.
2. Use the following sample code:

   ```
   [Designer(typeof(FixedHeightUserControlDesigner))]
   public partial class FixedHeightUserControl : UserControl
   {
       private const int FIXED_HEIGHT = 25;

       protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
       {
           if (this.Size.Height != FIXED_HEIGHT)
               this.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width, FIXED_HEIGHT);

           base.OnSizeChanged(e);
       }

       public FixedHeightUserControl()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           this.Height = FIXED_HEIGHT;
       }
   }

   public class FixedHeightUserControlDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
   {
       private static string[] _propsToRemove = new string[] { "Height", "Size" };

       public override SelectionRules SelectionRules
       {
           get { return SelectionRules.LeftSizeable | SelectionRules.RightSizeable | SelectionRules.Moveable; }
       }

       protected override void PreFilterProperties(System.Collections.IDictionary properties)
       {
           base.PreFilterProperties(properties);
           foreach (string p in _propsToRemove)
               if (properties.Contains(p))
                   properties.Remove(p);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You put in the work to answer the question, you get the +1 and accept!

Comment: Note that your designer class can instead inherit [`ControlDesigner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.aspx) rather than [`ParentControlDesigner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.parentcontroldesigner.aspx). Doing so will give your control the same "move" cursor that non-container controls have - you can move the control by clicking and dragging on it (almost) anywhere, rather than dragging from a certain icon/area, as you would have to do with a container control.

Comment: If you remove the "Size" prop then you loose the "Width" prop don't you?